# How to setup Apache as reverse proxy for odoo11 in windows server? Is that posiible?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, odoo, windows-server-2012, odoo-11

I need to link my subdomain with the Odoo 11 application which is running in windows server. I have been trying this for a while and ending up in finding the solution for ubuntu server. Please help me in understanding this.

Your help will be highly appreciable. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Odoo 11 listen to the default port 8069

So

1. Open the Apache virtual host configuration file that refer to your virtual host.
2. in the virtual host add these lines

   ```
   ####Proxy settings####

   Define ODOO_11_URL http://localhost:8069

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / ${ODOO_11_URL}
   ProxyPassReverse / {ODOO_11_URL}

   ####END Proxy settings####
   ```
3. If needed - Change the url as needed, for example if the url of Odoo 11 is http://localhost:8069/YOUR_URL - so change the line that start with "Define" to your url.

Answer (score 1):

Why Apache? IMO it will be better to use any other reverse proxy than Apache, one more focused on being a reverse proxy like [Traefik](https://traefik.io/) or [Nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) or [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) just to name a few that seems to live more in 2018 than Apache. Nothing against Apache, just that IMO there are some better tools for doing reverse proxy today